# freetype extracting character code from a glyph

Tags: freetype, freetype2

I would like to extract a character code in some form (a unicode character code, wchar_t or anything printable to a text format) from a `glyph_index` and an `FT_Face`. I know that there is a reverse function `FT_Get_Char_Index` for this purpose.

Although some glyphs may be composite, but is there any way to do the translation under some mild assumptions that the text is for example in the latin alphabet?